# Microsoft Enterprise Logger file roll over based on GMT

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I am using Microsoft Enterprise Logger for my application. I have given roll interval as Midnight.
Everything works perfectly as hoped but the problem is that it takes the local machine time to roll over. 
Is there a way to roll file based on GMT(or any other Time Zone to be more generic) not the local time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Rolling Flat File Trace Listeners uses the local machine time. For the roll to be based on an arbtirary timezone, use the [source](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/5/B/A5BF3B05-CB8A-40FE-B3E0-93FA84136D2B/Enterprise%20Library%205.0%20-%20Source%20Code.msi) provided and modify as necessary.

Also, if you want this to be added to the EntLib in the future, suggest it via the [uservoice](http://entlib.uservoice.com).

Comment: I searched whether I could do without modifying the source. But no other option. So I just modified the source just a day before you posted. Anyhow thanks for your valuable suggestion.